# Resampling produces Nans

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I resample data on 15 minutes based on 'time'. However it results Nans except first row for all the columns. What is the reason? Resampling works on 24H well.

```
pri=pri.resample('15min',on='Delivery Date').mean()
pri.head()
```

[Image Producing Nans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWQ6C.png)
[Original data head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNrTz.png)

Comment: It seems you have just one data point per hour in your original data. You can simply resample for time intervals bigger than 1 hour, otherwise, we need to interpolate your data in some way

Comment: i added original data image. there is 8 data per hour

Comment: mention everything like pri.resample(rule='15min',on='Delivery Date',axis=0).mean()

Comment: it doesnt work ,